# Would you say "Put the balloon on the stick" or "Put the balloon in the stick"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

A child can hold a balloon by its stick.

The stick has 2 parts: a straight stick and a conical piece.

The straight stick is put into the conical piece.

The conical piece has a gap or slot where you can slide the knot of the balloon in as shown in the picture.

Would you say "**Put the balloon on the stick**" or "**Put the balloon in the stick**" versus "**Take the balloon off the stick**" or "**Take the balloon out of the stick**" in everyday conversations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say *on the stick.* Whatever the mechanics of attaching it, the balloon ends up mounted on the end of the stick.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "attach the balloon to the stick."